# edit form - how to differentiate initial post from empty old value

Tags: laravel-8

In my add/edit form, I have several input tags that look like below:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control @error('prodCost') is-invalid @enderror" name="prodCost" id="prodCost" max="10000000" min="0"
     value="{{ old('prodCost') == null && isset($prod)? $prod->getCost()->getValue() : old('prodCost') }}"
```

> 

The code inside the value attribute is where I am having problem with.  The way that I am expecting it to work is like below:
On the initial post, since old('prodCost') is null, it will initialize the input value using the $prod object, and When I change the value to something invalid and submit it, it will retain the value that I have changed to and display the error.

It works like I have expected except when I change the value to empty string and submit it.  I am expecting it to display the error with empty string as the value.  But it is not.  This is because the empty string value causes the old('prodCost') == null condition to become true, which causes blade to initialize the value using the $prod object.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have conditionally value, so you need to `bind:` the value of your input.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control @error('prodCost') is-invalid @enderror" name="prodCost" id="prodCost" max="10000000" min="0"
     :value="old('prodCost') == null && isset($prod)? $prod->getCost()->getValue() : old('prodCost')" />
```